# Is this a good code to create a file model with Java?

Tags: java, jekyll, blogs

I have a blog hosted with Github Pages and powered by Jekyll.
To create a new post with Jekyll you need to put some info in the header of the file with at least the following details:

```
---
layout: [layout]
title: [title]
date: [date]
---
```

The filename must have the date in it. For example:

```
2016-10-21-name-of-the-post.md
```

I created a program in Java with a GUI to automatically format the file. So I only need to write the content. I would have to know if it is a good code. Where are the things to avoid? Note that I am a new programmer.

Here it is the code:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Post extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    // GUI THINGS
    JPanel pl = new JPanel();
    JTextField tfLayout = new JTextField("layout: default", 20);
    JTextField tfTitle = new JTextField("title:", 20);
    JTextField tffl = new JTextField("filename", 20);
    JTextArea tfDes = new JTextArea("Text",10,20);
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Post immediately");

    String filename = "/path/to/the/_posts/folder";
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    String layout = "";
    String title = "";
    String description = "";
    Date date = new Date();
    String actualdate = df.format(date);
    JTextField tfDate = new JTextField("date: " + actualdate);
    String format;

    public Post(){
        super("Nouveau post");
        filename += new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()) + "-";
        setContentPane(pl);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));
        tfDes.setLineWrap(true);
        tfDes.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        pl.add(tffl);
        pl.add(tfLayout);
        pl.add(tfTitle);
        pl.add(tfDate);
        pl.add(tfDes);
        pl.add(b1);

        b1.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Post window = new Post();
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setSize(400, 300);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {       
        layout = tfLayout.getText();
        filename += tffl.getText() + ".md";
        title = tfTitle.getText();
        description = tfDes.getText();
        actualdate = tfDate.getText();

        format = "---\n" + layout + "\n" + title + "\n" + actualdate +
            "\n---\n<p>" + description + "</p>";

        try {
            pw = new PrintWriter(filename, "UTF-8");
        } catch(IOException io) {
            System.out.println("ERROR while creating the file");
        }

        pw.print(format);
        pw.close();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Sucesssfully created a post.");
        this.dispose();  
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.

Comment: CK: Please note that this doesn't mean your question is bad, just that you'll find better answers over at Code Review. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is too general.

But I recommend splitting your code into Model-View-Presenter. Put the Post into its own class, put the view's logic into its own class and implement a presenter that handles your input. I also recommend reading some stuff about Clean Coding (e.g. by Robert C. Martin) if you have further interest in good code.

Also, make final variables for your constants.

Comment: If you find yourself answering "This question is too general", that's a good indicator that you shouldn't answer it.